# AWS suddenly throwing ssh error: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssh, public-key, openssh

I was using it without any issues. To install Nginx, PHP7, MySQL, Python, Go Lang and MongoDB, I had to change some user permissions in nginx.

Suddenly, I'm unable to ssh anymore!! I didn't touch the Amazon Console either. My colleague is also unable to ssh. I had given him the elaine.pem file

I was able to ssh using `ssh -i "elaine.pem" ubuntu@13.127.4.XXX` until now. No change and no spelling error.

Any thoughts?

```
Elaine-MacBook-Pro:key elaine$ ssh -v -i "elaine.pem" ubuntu@13.127.4.XXX
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 13.127.4.xxx [13.127.4.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file elaine.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file elaine.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 13.127.4.xxx:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Z4mp+ciY2V+zjJn4G6Un3kv4A9xZ7AOZ9lQ2V9FZthw
debug1: Host '13.127.4.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/elaine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: elaine.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: elaine.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
Elaine-MacBook-Pro:key elaine$
```

Comment: as a side note, please don't give your private key to someone else. And changing the user permission in nginx won't cause the permission denied. Try use the `root` user and make sure port `22` is opened

Comment: He's my colleague working together. Can't login with root but with ubuntu. Also all ports are open in the Security.

Comment: A better approach is to create another Key Pair. One for each of you.

Comment: Check that the IP address you are connecting to is correct.

Comment: Then you've lost something in the `.ssh` directory of the ubuntu user.  If you can't recreate the machine easily then you'll need to [follow the AWS instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair) to create a new key pair.

Comment: maybe when you change permission, you changed permission of current user to `~/.ssh` directory or some other things relative to ssh permission. Use AWS Console to check system log.